# When a catamaran heels over

Tags: displacement

When a sailboat catamaran is sailing in displacement mode and heels over enough so that only one hull is in the water will 100% of the weight of the boat be on that hull, will that hull have to displace 100% of the weight of the boat?

Comment: That depends on whether or not you want it to keep floating...

Comment: I want it stay floating

Comment: Yes, it will but there are a lot of forces acting on the cat, besides mere gravity!

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, modern boats, including sailboats, displace 100% of their weight only at rest. When a boat is moving its hull generates some lift that partially lifts the boat from the water. Some boats have hydrofoils capable of lifting the boats almost completely out of the water. Here are some extreme examples:

[Moth sailboats](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZU_SqMW_5Y) lift out of the water almost completely.

[Oracle catamaran](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55Skt_Q5Byg), the one that won America's cup, also uses hydrofoils.

Notice that when Oracle catamaran is tacking (changing course relative to the wind direction) it lowers the hydrofoil on the leeward side and lifts the hydrofoil on the windward side. That's because in high enough wind catamaran usually doesn't need any support from its windward hull, whether by displacement or hydrofoil: the windward hull is kept out of the water by the angular force acting on the sail. And yes, the combined force of dynamic lift and displacement acting on the leeward hull has to add up to 100% of the catamaran's weight.